# ¿Cómo consultar en git los commits en los que se modificó un archivo?

Tags: git

Tengo un repositorio de Git de una aplicación corporativa que tiene poco más de 11 años de desarrollo. El tamaño del repositorio es de cerca de 4,3GB. En el proyecto se encuentra un archivo de nombre "X" en el cual estoy trabajando. ¿Cómo podría usar Git para consultar las modificaciones que en todos estos años se han hecho sobre el archivo?

Como información adicional:

1. El tamaño del repositorio es bastante grande.
2. El archivo ha sido renombrado una o varias veces durante todo este tiempo.
3. El archivo que me interesa fue cambiado de ubicación en el repositorio.
4. El IDE que uso para el desarrollo y mantenimiento de la aplicación está basado en Eclipse (Spring Tool Suite) y este tiene una opción de Git integrada que me permite ver los commits que modificaron un archivo, pero sólo me permite ver desde un momento que sé que no es el de creación (un commit en el que en realidad se renombró el archivo, sin decirme el nombre anterior).

Si con Git no es posible, pero existe alguna aplicación que me permita hacer esto, también sería de ayuda.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para obtener el historial de cambios de un archivo específico existe la opción `--follow` del `git log`

```
git log --follow -- nombreArchivo
```

- Los `--` antes de `nombreArchivo` sirven para indicar explícitamente que `nombreArchivo` corresponde a un archivo (y no, por ejemplo, al nombre de una rama).

Si quieres que te entregue esta información en formato *parche* (*patch*), entonces debes ejecutar:

```
git log --follow -p -- nombreArchivo
```

---

La documentación del comando `log` la puedes consultar en inglés (no la encontré en español):

[Git - git-log Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

Busqué en la [traducción al español del libro de GIT](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1), y tampoco encontré la opción `--follow`.

Comment: Increible esa opción, no la conocía. Quizás estaría bueno aclarar que combiene usar `git log --follow -- nombreArchivo` para evitar el caso en que nombreArchivo es justo el nombre de una rama. Además se puede combinar con la opción `-L` para mirar la evolución de una función particular.

Comment: @eloyesp muy buen detalle lo de `--`, lo acabo de incorporar a la respuesta.

Comment: Me gusta esta solución, a pesar que me genera una traza muy grande de cambios y me gustaría poder contar con alguna herramienta que me mostrara esta misma información de mejor manera. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Para complementar la respuesta de Nicolás, si quieres ver qué línea modificó cada commit, también puedes usar [`git blame [opciones] -- archivo`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) (documentación original en inglés).